# Normalizer of the cyclic group in $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $g\in A_n$ be a cycle of length $n$ (if $n$ is odd) or $n-1$ (if $n$ is even), we know that $C_{S_n}(g)=C_{A_n}(g)$, where $C_G(g)$ denote the centralizer of $g$ in $G$.

My question is : **For what values of $n$, we have $N_{S_n}(\langle g \rangle)=N_{A_n}(\langle g \rangle)$, where $N_G(\langle g \rangle)$ denotes the normalizer of $\langle g \rangle$ in $G$.**

I know if $n$ is of type $4k+3$ or $4k$ type, then $N_{S_n}(\langle g \rangle)\neq N_{A_n}(\langle g \rangle)$. Here is the proof:
Let $g=(1,2,3,\dots, 4k+3)$, take $h:=(2,4k+3)(3,4k+2)\dots(2k+2,2k+3)$
then $hgh^{-1}=g^{-1}$ and $h\in N_{S_n}(\langle g \rangle)$ but $h\notin N_{A_n}(\langle g \rangle)$ as $h\notin A_n$

but in case n=4k+1 then for n=5, $N_{S_n}(\langle g \rangle)\neq N_{A_n}(\langle g \rangle)$ and for n=9, $N_{S_n}(\langle g \rangle)=N_{A_n}(\langle g \rangle)$

Comment: Rather than just ask a question with no context, you should make some comments about it yourself, like not if $n$ is prime and not if $n \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. Also, you might as well assume that $n$ is odd.

Comment: Experimental evidence suggests that the answer for odd $n$ is yes if and only if $n$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Thank you... I have edited the question and added what I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by a comment of Derek Holt I prove his conjecture for an odd integer $n$.

First of all I propose the notation $C_u$ for the cyclic group of order $u$.
The solution to this problem boils down to the analysis of the structure of the normalizer $N$ of $C_n = \langle g \rangle$, where $g$ is the cycle $(1,2,\ldots,n)$, in $S_n$ and show when all the permutations in $N$ are even and thus $N \subset A_n$ or not. It can be seen that this normalizer is the semidirect product $N = C_n \rtimes H$, where H is a subgroup of $S_n$ isomorphic to the automorphism group of $C_n$. Since $C_n \subset A_n$ our interest solely goes to the group $H$. At the end I provide an explicit example where every detail is highlighted so one can skip there now.

To construct $H$ as a subgroup of $N$ it suffices to consider the set of permutations $n_u$ defined by:
$$
n_u : i \mapsto 1 + u(i-1)\mod(n) \text{ where } i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \text{ and } \gcd(u,n) = 1  
$$ 
It is not difficult to see that these make up the group $H$ since $g^u = g^{n_u}$.

Now let $p^k$ be one of the prime power factors of $n$, i.e. $n = p^km$ with $\gcd(p, m) = 1$. Then $H = C_{\varphi(p^k)} \times M$. The group $C_{\varphi(p^k)}$ can be obtained by restricting the $u$ to the condition $u = 1 \mod(m)$. The abelian group $M$ of order $\varphi(m)$ is of no interest. Moreover $C_{\varphi(p^k)} = C_{p-1} \times C_{p^{k-1}}$ and since $C_{p^{k-1}}$ only consists of even permutations our interest goes to the group $C_{p-1}$. It can be calculated that there are exactly $m$ points fixed by $C_{p-1}$ so that the number of points moved by $C_{p-1}$ is $p^km-m = (p^k-1)m$. Let $p$ be a generator of the group $C_{p-1}$, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184704/decomposition-of-a-permutation-giving-cycles-of-equal-lengtth/2185723#2185723) $p$ decomposes in cycles that are all of length $p-1$ (and so are odd permutations) therefor their number is $\frac{p^k-1}{p-1}m = m(p^{k-1}+\ldots+p^2+p+1)$ so if $k$ is even then there are an even number of cycles and all the permutations of $C_{\varphi(p^k)}$ are even, and if $k$ is odd there is at least one odd permutation in $H$. We conlude that all the permutations of $H$ are even iff all the exponents of the prime power decompostion of $n$ are even, in other words if $n$ is a perfect square.

---

**Example**  $n = 5^33^2 =1125$

we have $g = (1,2,\ldots,1125)$. The normalizer of $C_{1125}$ is the semidirect  product of $C_{1125}$  and $H$, a subgroup of $S_n$. As a subgroup of $S_n$ H can be constructed as the permutations 
$$
n_u : i \mapsto u(i-1) \mod(1125) \text{ for } i\in \{1,\ldots,1125\}
$$ Where the $u$ are coprime to $n$.
The structure of $H$ as automorphism group of $C_{1125}$ has the structure $C_4 \rtimes C_{25} \times M$.The number of fixed points of $C_4$ is $9$ (namely $1, 126, 251,\ldots, 876, 1001 $) so the number of moved points by $C_4$ is $5^39-9 = 9(5^3-1)$ making space for $\frac{5^3-1}{5-1}$ odd cycles of lenght $4$, but $\frac{5^3-1}{5-1} = 5^2+5+1 = 31$ is odd so $H$ possesses an odd permutation. If the exponent of $5$ had been even (e.g. 4) then $\frac{5^4-1}{5-1}= 5^3+5^2+5+1$, the sum of an even number of odd terms thus giving an even number of odd permutations and so we had to have looked up the next factor $3^2$ to effectively conclude that $H$ contains only even permutations.