# Conjecture in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering if the following could be proven or disproven: For any $H \le A_n$, $N_{A_n}(H)\neq N_{S_n}(H)$, where $n \neq 1$. If this is too easy can we consider the special case where $H$ is cyclic.

It can easily be seen through the Second Isomorphism Theorem, that an equivalent statement for $N_{A_n}(H)\neq N_{S_n}(H)$, is $2|N_{A_n}(H)|= |N_{S_n}(H)|$, or by the Orbit-Stabiliser theorem, another equivalent statement is that the conjugates of $H$ in $A_n$ and in $S_n$ are the same.

I have checked that the conjecture holds for $n$ up to $5$.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2169737/473276) post shows the conjecture is not even true for cyclic $H$. In particular, in $A_9$, the normaliser of the subgroup generated by a $9$-cycle is the same as in $S_9$.

Comment: That's an *answer*, @IzaakvanDongen, not a *comment*.

Comment: @Shaun, I think this question is basically a duplicate, and as I understand it answering duplicates is [not encouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/473276). Since the linked post is a bit dense and addresses the "special case" of this question I thought I'd link and give a short explanation of its relevance to see if OP is happy with that. Have I got the wrong idea? If you like you're welcome to write an answer containing the text of my comment!

Comment: The smallest counterexample to the general question is a subgroup of order $12$ in $A_7$.

Comment: I can see why that's a duplicate, so I have closed it, @IzaakvanDongen. Thank you.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks for your reply